# Getting started with client-created Oauth2 Authorisation

Tags: javascript, php, google-oauth

I'm developing a "plugin" for a form designer, and want to create a set of Google actions for the website owner to add to the submit event of their website's form. The general idea is that the website owner will drag for example a Save to Google Sheets action to the submit event, so the website owner can save the user's form responses to the website owner's Google Sheet.

What I need is help on exactly where to start. Google documentation is very dense and I'm going in circles trying to understand it. The "plugin" comes in two parts.
1) A plugin_name_configuration.php file detailing the HTML fields for the backend settings of the plugin
2) A plugin_name_output.php file that is executed when the action is run on the server.

Because this is a plugin a website owner will install on their own website, I assume there are some OAuth methods that wouldn't be appropriate. I also don't know if I should be creating the OAuth consent screen and API keys, or if it should be like Google Maps / reCaptcha plugins, where the website owner is expected to generate their own API keys. There are also Service Accounts, which I'm struggling to understand.

What I really need is help pointing me in the right direction. I don't know where to start so I'm basically paralysed.

NOTE: when I say "website owner" that's not just one person, this is a plugin that can be added to any installation of the form builder on any website. It's not being made for just one guy.

Comment: It's not really Joomla specific though, and doesn't require I use any Joomla classes or methods or anything. Plus the component is also for WordPress.

Comment: I would suggest adding a callback file as well, as an OAuth API is going include a callback page to send the authorization request after the user logs in. It could possibly be the same as one of the main files as long as you are checking whether you already have a refresh token set.

Comment: Definitely do have each plugin user manage their own API keys. You don't want to hand yours over to any user on the web. You could potentially run up a large bill for data use if people realize there is a "free" API key out there for anyone to use.

Answer (score 0):

So after much searching and hair pulling I figured it out, or at least figured what I think is the right way to proceed.

Using hints from https://flaviocopes.com/google-api-authentication/, in my backend I will have the web owner specify the path to their JSON authentication file and authenticate using a Service Account Key.